# How to print receipt with PAX a 920?

Tags: java, android, pos, pax

I have Pax A920 which runs with android .
So how to using printing service in java?

Comment: Please contact the vendor's support desk. [Terminal — PAX A920](https://ventrata.com/solutions/hardware/terminal-pax-a920/)

Comment: Vendo's not responding

Comment: If there is no way to ask the sales company that handles it, there seems to be no way. You just have to wait for someone you know to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use the Neptune api. you can google pax 920 neptune api demo and the fist link that shows up (https://docs.hips.com/docs/pax-a920) contains a demo that shows all the basic functions (including the printer) and you can run it on your device:

In the Application you first need a function to retrieve the IDAL:

```
public static IDAL getDal() {
    if(dal == null){ //dal is a private static IDAL variable of the application
        try {
            dal = NeptuneLiteUser.getInstance().getDal(context);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    return dal;
}
```

then in your activity you can just do the following:

```
try {
    IPrinter printer=   MyApp.getDal().getPrinter();
    printer.init();
    printer.printStr("Your text",null);
    printer.start();
} catch (PrinterDevException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to use `void setFontPath(java.lang.String fontPath)` function?

Comment: @MohamedMedhat nope sorry, I had to change my font only slightly and I used `void fontSet(EFontTypeAscii asciiFontType,EFontTypeExtCode fontTypeExtCode)`
Did you try giving it the path of a .ttf file? Still, I would be surprised if it worked with any type of font

Comment: tried a lot but no luck :(